# Saving a table to an XML file

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008

I am currently working on a website. I have been asked to be able to allow admins to save tables in the database to an XML file (so they can download it from their browser).

I don't even know where to begin. I've done multiple hours of research but this process doesn't seem very well documented. I would appreciate some pointers in the right direction, or if possible, a more in-depth explanation.

How would I set-up my files? How can I make them download that file instead of saving it into my application? How would I even save it to an XML file to start?

I've seen some stuff online about backing your database into an XML file, but I feel that this is different as it allows users to download a database file instead of the developer making one.

**EDIT**

For clarity's sake the XML should resemble the database.
So, if I have a Product (or products), I would hope the XML looks something similar to the following:

```
<product>
     <title>
          My Product
     </title>
     <price>
          5.00
     </price>
     <quantity>
          4
     </quantity>
     <description>
          This is my product!
     </description>
</product>
```

Comment: Vote to close - unclear what you have problem with. You've listed multiple steps that you need to figure out, but no problems (how your XMLs should look like, how to download file in ASP.Net, how to save XML).

Comment: Consider showing an effort that you actually searched for anything like http://www.bing.com/search?q=download+file+in+ASP.Net .

Comment: With all due respect Alexei, I don't see how me posting links is beneficial to anyone. I can however assure you I've looked into DataSets, the XML Schema Editor, and countless of links asking similar questions. I understand my question may be broad, and I'm willing to narrow it down into smaller questions. I also understand the frustration of trying to help people who refuse to do any of their own research, but rest assured, StackOverflow is usually my last resort.

Comment: You magically solved at first of your problems - how your XML should look like. Second link in search I gave gives you and answer to "how to download file" - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478985.aspx#aspnet-jspmig-downloadinganduploading_topic6 and the rest is given by Aaron Bertrand... for future consider making questions more scoped so answer can be given directly.

Comment: But my question was to be given pointers in the right direction, and Aaron provided those very nicely. Maybe it's just because I'm having a bad day but I don't like the tone of your comments and I feel that you are mocking me. But understand I'm not looking for any free rides. I respect the StackOverflow community and the insight they provide. I don't come here to ask others to solve problems I'm too lazy to solve. I come here to get help with problems that I am in the process of solving myself. All of this is a learning process for me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10769/discussion-between-alexei-levenkov-and-johannes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The query you might want is:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 etc.
  FROM dbo.TableName
  FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS;
```

Run that in Management Studio to see what it returns. I think you need to split your question into multiple parts. This one is how you generate XML from a table. A different question will be how to consume that from C# and save it to a file. These questions might give you a head start, but I don't know if you will need to do anything differently in MVC3 (I know how to spell it, but not much else):

[How to save this string into XML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721735/how-to-save-this-string-into-xml-file)

[Save xml string or XmlNode to text file in indent format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816109/save-xml-string-or-xmlnode-to-text-file-in-indent-format)

Comment: I do appreciate this, sometimes I forget to just break down the problem into several smaller ones!